# am having issues launching my rails server using terminal. I have attached a screen shot of my issue! hope someone can help! Thanks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when i try to run rails server i get the following error! would be GREAT if someone could help!

[Below is a screenshot of my code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntu05.jpg)

Comment: Did you read the error? Have you tried running `webpacker:install`  It says the `webpacker.yml` file is missing.  The error seems to explain exactly what you need to do doesn't it? Or did that not work?

Comment: lease do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors.

Answer (score 0):

As your error log is saying 'Webpacker configuration file is not found', you need to run `rails webpacker:install` as given in error logs suggestion and try starting your server again.

Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58252546/9273735)